# Как решить проблему фиксациии блока при прокрутке?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть блок1, который фиксируется при прокрутке страницы, он работает корректно до тех пор, пока не кликнуть на переключатель, и не появится блок2. После того как появился блок2, блок1, который фиксируется,  срабатывает раньше времени и получается, что блок1 прыгает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#switch-track').click(function() {

    $('input#switch-track').prop('checked', function() {
      $(".track-option").slideToggle();
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  function fixedFilter() {
    var accountFilter = $('.account__filter'),
      topAccountFilter = $(accountFilter).offset().top,
      heightHeader = $('.header').height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + heightHeader;
      if (windowScroll > topAccountFilter) {
        $(accountFilter).addClass('account__filter--fixed');
      } else {
        $(accountFilter).removeClass('account__filter--fixed');
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(fixedFilter);
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    fixedFilter();
  });
});
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body,
input,
button,
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-top: 95px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  background: url("../img/header/header-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.header::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 23, 0.75);
}

.switch__container {
  position: relative;
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.switch__label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  border: 1px solid #181818;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch__label::before,
.switch__label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #353535;
  border-radius: 8px 8px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.switch__label::before {
  left: 10px;
}

.switch__label::after {
  right: 10px;
}

.switch__toggle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 208, 190, 0.09);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.switch__toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #2af598 0%, #08aeea 100%, #a0d8ff 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label::before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label::after {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label .switch__toggle {
  left: calc(67px - 40px);
  background-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.09);
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label .switch__toggle::after {
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #363636 0%, #363636 100%);
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  opacity: .5;
}

.account-track {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.account-track__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 1.85%;
}

.account-track__col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #181818;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
  border-radius: 2px 2px;
}

.account-track__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.account-track__title {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.account-track__name {
  margin-right: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.account-track__more {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #424242;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.account-track__more::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAOCAMAAAAolt3jAAAAM1BMVEVgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZHcExgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGb8SgemAAAAEXRSTlN9HF9VJARPNwB1aHAWD0EQLjWxu1gAAABdSURBVAgdBcGBYcIwEAAxBez8GWjp/tNWUrXXzNpVqjlwplI3wF0aeH2fmOwDr+uBsy3wOGAZeP5cYAz4XGAsePcLln3w7AFna/D6/L0xqRvgLtUcOFOp2mtm7ap/OYsDCqMFCewAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") no-repeat;
}

.account-track__desc {
  color: #fff;
}

.account-track__switch {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 123px;
}

.account-track__switch::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  bottom: 21%;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: #212123;
}

.track-option {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.64);
  display: none;
}

.track-option__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0 28px;
  width: 78.5%;
}

.track-option__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.track-option__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
}

.track-option__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 44px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #272727;
}

.account-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.account__filter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 90px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(129, 129, 129, 0.39);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}

.account__filter--fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 95px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  /*transition: top .5s linear;*/
  ;
}

.account__filter-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.account__filter-form fieldset {
  width: 100%;
}

.account__filter-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1.85%;
  height: 100%;
}

.account__product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 30px 1.85% 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <header class="header">
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="account-track">
      <div class="account-track__container">
        <div class="account-track__col">
          <div class="account-track__content">
            <div class="account-track__title">
              <span class="account-track__name">Track Account </span>
              <span class="account-track__more">Learn more</span>
            </div>
            <p class="account-track__desc">Save this trip to track price changes and receive price alerts and travel tips by email</p>
          </div>
          <div class="account-track__switch">
            <form action="#" class="switch__form">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="switch__container">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-track">
                  <label for="switch-track" class="switch__label">
           <span class="switch__toggle"></span>
          </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="track-option">
        <form action="#" class="track-option__form">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="track-option__container">
              <h1 class="track-option__title">БЛОК 2</h2>
                <p class="track-option__subtitle">Testing text, bla, yo</p>
                <div class="track-option__content">
                </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="account-content">
      <div class="account__filter">
        <form action="#" class="account__filter-form">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="account__filter-container">
              <h2>БЛОК 1</h2>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="account__product">
        <p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>5Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>6Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>7Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>8Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>9Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>10Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>11Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>12Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>13Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>14Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>15Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>16Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>17Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>18Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>19Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>20Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>21Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>22Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>23Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>24Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>25Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>26Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>27Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>28Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>29Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>30Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь я не видел ту ошибку которую вы говорили в вопросе

Comment: @Raz Galstyan Вы разверните на всю страницу, так будет виднее, либо вот ссылка https://jsfiddle.net/g9snennj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто после включения второго блока, нужно снова вызвать `fixedFilter()`, потому что высота изменилась

```js
function fixedFilter() {
  var accountFilter = $('.account__filter'),
    topAccountFilter = $(accountFilter).offset().top,
    heightHeader = $('.header').height();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + heightHeader;
    if (windowScroll > topAccountFilter) {
      $(accountFilter).addClass('account__filter--fixed');
    } else {
      $(accountFilter).removeClass('account__filter--fixed');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fixedFilter();
  $('input#switch-track').click(function() {
    $('input#switch-track').prop('checked', function() {
      $(".track-option").slideToggle(1000, function() {
        fixedFilter();
      });
    });
  });
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    fixedFilter();
  });
});
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body,
input,
button,
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-top: 95px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  background: url("../img/header/header-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.header::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 23, 0.75);
}

.switch__container {
  position: relative;
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.switch__label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  border: 1px solid #181818;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch__label::before,
.switch__label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #353535;
  border-radius: 8px 8px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.switch__label::before {
  left: 10px;
}

.switch__label::after {
  right: 10px;
}

.switch__toggle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 208, 190, 0.09);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.switch__toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #2af598 0%, #08aeea 100%, #a0d8ff 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label::before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label::after {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label .switch__toggle {
  left: calc(67px - 40px);
  background-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.09);
}

.switch__form input[type=checkbox]:checked+.switch__label .switch__toggle::after {
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #363636 0%, #363636 100%);
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  opacity: .5;
}

.account-track {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.account-track__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 1.85%;
}

.account-track__col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #181818;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
  border-radius: 2px 2px;
}

.account-track__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.account-track__title {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.account-track__name {
  margin-right: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.account-track__more {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #424242;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.account-track__more::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAOCAMAAAAolt3jAAAAM1BMVEVgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZHcExgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGZgYGb8SgemAAAAEXRSTlN9HF9VJARPNwB1aHAWD0EQLjWxu1gAAABdSURBVAgdBcGBYcIwEAAxBez8GWjp/tNWUrXXzNpVqjlwplI3wF0aeH2fmOwDr+uBsy3wOGAZeP5cYAz4XGAsePcLln3w7AFna/D6/L0xqRvgLtUcOFOp2mtm7ap/OYsDCqMFCewAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") no-repeat;
}

.account-track__desc {
  color: #fff;
}

.account-track__switch {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 123px;
}

.account-track__switch::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  bottom: 21%;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: #212123;
}

.track-option {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.64);
  display: none;
}

.track-option__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0 28px;
  width: 78.5%;
}

.track-option__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.track-option__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21);
}

.track-option__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 44px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #272727;
}

.account-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.account__filter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 90px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(129, 129, 129, 0.39);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}

.account__filter--fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 95px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  /*transition: top .5s linear;*/
  ;
}

.account__filter-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.account__filter-form fieldset {
  width: 100%;
}

.account__filter-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1.85%;
  height: 100%;
}

.account__product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 30px 1.85% 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <header class="header">
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="account-track">
      <div class="account-track__container">
        <div class="account-track__col">
          <div class="account-track__content">
            <div class="account-track__title">
              <span class="account-track__name">Track Account </span>
              <span class="account-track__more">Learn more</span>
            </div>
            <p class="account-track__desc">Save this trip to track price changes and receive price alerts and travel tips by email</p>
          </div>
          <div class="account-track__switch">
            <form action="#" class="switch__form">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="switch__container">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-track">
                  <label for="switch-track" class="switch__label">
           <span class="switch__toggle"></span>
          </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="track-option">
        <form action="#" class="track-option__form">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="track-option__container">
              <h1 class="track-option__title">БЛОК 2</h2>
                <p class="track-option__subtitle">Testing text, bla, yo</p>
                <div class="track-option__content">
                </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="account-content">
      <div class="account__filter">
        <form action="#" class="account__filter-form">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="account__filter-container">
              <h2>БЛОК 1</h2>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="account__product">
        <p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>5Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>6Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>7Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>8Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>9Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>10Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>11Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>12Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>13Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>14Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>15Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>16Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>17Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>18Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>19Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>20Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>21Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>22Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>23Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>24Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>25Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>26Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>27Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>28Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>29Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
        <p>30Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum esse autem, non rem facilis nobis eius alias sapiente omnis, soluta quidem commodi. Sequi libero possimus, accusamus! Incidunt omnis, dolorem reprehenderit!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!